# Firefox addon for elasticsearch

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, elasticsearch

Chrome has a nice extension, called [Sense](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense/doinijnbnggojdlcjifpdckfokbbfpbo), for elasticsearch. But I could not find a similar addon for Firefox.

Can you recommend me one?

Comment: Sense has been "merge" into Kibana, so you must install Kibana and you can use Sense via Firefox.